# Low performance on React Native maps when components are used inside of marker

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am making a react native map, using MapView from 'react-native-maps' and [this marker clustering engine](https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-maps-super-cluster). This is the component for a cluster marker that has been working just fine with blazing performance:

```
export default class ClusterMarker extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      tracksViewChanges: true
    }
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props !== nextProps) {
      this.setState(() => ({
        tracksViewChanges: true,
      }))
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.tracksViewChanges) {
      this.setState(() => ({
        tracksViewChanges: false,
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {    
    /*... 
      bunch of unrelated code where 'message', 'image', 'coordinate' and 'pointCount' are set
    ...*/
    return (
        <Marker
            anchor={{x:0.5,y:0.5}}
            centerOffset={{x:0.5,y:0.5}}
            coordinate={coordinate}
            image={image}
            title={pointCount}
            description={message}
            tracksViewChanges={this.state.tracksViewChanges}>
            {/* <Text>{pointCount}</Text> */}    <-------- I want this to work just as fast
        </Marker>
    )
  }
}
```

See that `title={pointCount}` in Marker props? When a user clicks a cluster, an overlay pops up to show them how many pins are there in the cluster. I want to bring that text out of there and display it over the cluster. Note that in render inside Marker, there is a commented line. When uncommented, visually it does pretty much what is needed, but with a terrible perfomance on phone (1 fps would be an overstatement).

It's clear that the problem is with Text. My hypothesis is that the Text component keeps on checking parent if there are updates on text, or that it re-renders all the time for no reason. Here is a list of things I've tried to fix this:

- Create a component extending from Text, performing the same task without weird updates or re-renders. No fps increase.
- Create a component that renders a Text but never updates or re-renders for no reason. No fps increase.
- Add the `tracksViewChanges` logic you can see above. That was somewhat of a success, increasing average fps from 1 to 5.
- Use other marker clustering libs (all of which failed to work with decent performance even without the Text inside Marker).
- Many hacky solutions from the internet, none of which actually improved performace.

This map is currently dealing with an average of 20,000 pins and the solution has to be performant as this pin count increases, because it will.

I would be very glad if anyone could help!

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I also have 15k points clustered into a couple of markers and by checking React Profiler, using a custom marker has a 4-10x performance hit on render time (from 20-30ms to 100-200ms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is not the answer you are looking for, but 20k markers is... a lot. Have you considered clustering the markers based on the zoom level? You could also filter out markers that are not in the map viewport.

Comment: The thing is, it works perfectly fine as it currently is even for older phones. I'm clustering by zoom levels and also filtered as much as I could. It should be possible to put a dumb static text there without taking a huge hit in performance like that, because it is working fine as it is. Also it's not 20k markers, it's 20k pins that get clustered, chaged it in the question, sorry for the misunderstanding.